# How to play two audio files simultaneously with real time size value with NAudio

Tags: c#, audio, real-time, naudio

the first I'm working with NAudio, so need your help

Same way as I got here real-time from default audio source, how can I get two audio wav or mp3 files, in this case must be direct inputs I guess, to play it both simultaneously with real-time value. Just same way as it shown below, but at the same time, to get current peaks size from each. What and how I have to use for this goal in my C# Windows Form Application. I was looking for in the sources, but I found nothing, some examples does not works for me, seems need some setups, so to check everything, better get practical and direct example or advice

```
using NAudio.CoreAudioApi;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace XX_9_REAL_TIME_AUDIO
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MMDeviceEnumerator enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
            var devices = enumerator.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow.All, DeviceState.Active);
            comboBox1.Items.AddRange(devices.ToArray());
        }

        private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboBox1.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                var device = (MMDevice)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
                progressBar1.Value = (int) (Math.Round(device.AudioMeterInformation.MasterPeakValue * 100 + 0.5));


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here I got wav file, but have no idea how to get real time value for it and how to play another one at the same time:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using NAudio.Wave;

namespace NAudioTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static IWavePlayer waveout;
        static WaveStream outputStream;
        static string filename = null;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            waveout = new WaveOutEvent();

            filename ="C:\\folder\\track.wav";

            outputStream = CreateInputStream(filename);

            try
            {
                waveout.Init(outputStream);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error while loading output");
                Console.WriteLine("Details: " + ex.Message);
                Console.ReadLine();
                return;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press [Enter] to start playback");
            Console.ReadLine();

            waveout.Play(); //this stops after 1 sec. should it play until i hit enter cause of the next line?

            Console.WriteLine("Press [Enter] to abort");
            Console.ReadLine();
            waveout.Dispose();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


        static WaveStream CreateInputStream(string name)
        {
            WaveChannel32 inputStream;
            if (name.EndsWith(".wav"))
            {
                WaveStream readerStream = new WaveFileReader(name);
                if (readerStream.WaveFormat.Encoding != WaveFormatEncoding.Pcm)
                {
                    readerStream = WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(readerStream);
                    readerStream = new BlockAlignReductionStream(readerStream);
                }

                if (readerStream.WaveFormat.BitsPerSample != 16)
                {
                    var format = new WaveFormat(readerStream.WaveFormat.SampleRate, 16, readerStream.WaveFormat.Channels);
                    readerStream = new WaveFormatConversionStream(format, readerStream);
                }
                inputStream = new WaveChannel32(readerStream);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid extension");
            }
            return inputStream;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To play multiple files simultaneously (which is what I think you are asking to do), you should create an `AudioFileReader` for each of the input files. And then connect each of those as inputs to a `MixingSampleProvider`. Then initialize your output audio device with the `MixingSampleProvider`

Comment: first want to say thank you  for  your great work!  hope now I can figure out with my problem following this instructions.  All tutorials  I've seen does not shows what I want and I could not find  some demo project on https://naudio.codeplex.com/ corresponding to this issue, because it is first time I have deal with NAudio, and  just not sure what to use. So maybe, if you can give me some useful link for my case just to understand  how it works, would be great. and thank you for your feedback again